# British Airways from Charles de Gaulle to Bangalore

Tags: transit

I am traveling from Paris to Bangalore via London Heathrow on British Airways as I don't have to change the terminal at LHR

Kindly advise if I will need a transit visa, as my onward is booked to US from bangalore